# Redirecting in CefGlue

Tags: c#, redirect, chromium-embedded, cefglue

I'm trying to create a CefResponse from this redirection test Url : http://httpbin.org/redirect/1
 It's a 302 redirection to http://httpbin.org/get

In my GetResponseHeaders override, I perform the following actions:

```
/// <summary>
/// Retrieve response header information.
/// http://xilium.bitbucket.org/cefglue/doc/html/AE00F235.htm
/// </summary>
protected override void GetResponseHeaders(CefResponse response, out long responseLength, out string redirectUrl)
{
    CefResponse wrcResponse = _cefUrlRequestClient.Response;

    responseLength = _cefUrlRequestClient.DataLength;

    if (wrcResponse.Status == 302) // probably should look for other 3xx redirects
    {
        // Redirect using HTTP 302

        // TODO Redirection .....

    }

}
```

But response.Status is always 200 not 302

How do we achieve redirecting in CefGlue?

Thanks in advance.